# Node.js are not running

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using macOs High Sierra, trying to run small node.js code `node server.js`, from iTerm, showing this error:

```
module.js:545

        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module '/Users/vikasenkova/server.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:666:3
```

Cant't find solution here.. if somebody knows..Found this link https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689 when trying to delete files with this: `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules` showing that permission denied. Nothing helps.

Comment: The command `node server.js` will expect that a `server.js` file exists within the terminal's current directory. Try including the full path (`node /full/path/to/server.js`) or change directory before starting Node (`cd /full/path/to`, then `node server.js`).

Comment: Please check the path even before running the js file on node.Move in to the directory where the file exists and then try your run command node filename.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your running in the same directory as the server.js file. Also update your question with some code to get more specific answer. Hope it helps you.